# UrlConnection.getHeaderField(string name) returning null

Tags: java, http, http-headers

working on a URlconnection problem

The connection object is created by invoking the openConnection() method on a URL and the general request is manipualted. then i initialized a string in which i am expecting a uniqueid from the function getHeaderfield(string name). After that i need to perform actual connection to the remote object using connect() method

```
   call for openConnection()
   String uniqueid=null;
   call for connect()
   uniqueid=UrlConnection.getHeaderField(Headername);
```

here i am getting the value of uniqueid as null.

When i researched on topic i get to know that the actual function getHeaderField(string) returns null only (found in rt.jar in java package under java.net.UrlConection.class).

But the oracle docs says 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29
that it returns the value of the named header. Can anyone explain the behaviour of getHeaderField()method ?

Answer (score 5):

The UrlConnection in java.net is abstract, therefore the UrlConnection you're working with is probably a subclass (could be anonymous).

Try printing out the class name of the UrlConnection with .getClass() to what you're actually working with, then look at that documentation.

As to why you're getting null, I'd guess your supplied headerName doesn't match anything in the header. Try getting the map of all headers with .getHeaderFields() and print the keySet() to see if your header is in there.

Comment: The `getHeaderFields()` method showed me exactly which headers got returned.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

getHeaderFields() may return null if there is no Mobile Data or WiFi connection.